# Project Server Sharing resources across departments

Tags: project-management, project-server, ms-project-server-2013

Microsoft Project Server 2013, I am newbie , I had a system under MSProfessional to see capacity when I had just parts of people

We have a number of staff that work % of time in multiple departments, is there a way of seeing the total capacity of  a department e.g. Software Department when we have staff  say 50% on SW and 50% on help desk

Also this  applies to role so  we expect staff to have  multiple roles  so when working on Help desk they have a different role to Developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Microsoft Project there are many different ways to accomplish this.  I know, this is a "programming" site and I have used it for query help in the past but what you are asking for is built into Project already without having to go into development mode.  One way you can do this is with one or two custom fields.  Or, you could use the RBS and the units on each Resource.  I know that the goal is to answer the question but this is one of those questions that is pretty wide open because there are two or three good solutions but each are based on a different business scenario.  So, in the spirit of giving a path to do this I would suggest that you add a custom field for each resource with the department classification and then also put in the Resource's capacity and then you can run as many slices of this data as you want from the Resource Center.  That will show you availability versus capacity and workload.  You also mention roles, you may use a skill set field for that and use that as another method of slicing this data.  Again, many choices to get that data directly from the system....

Answer (score 0):

In the end I was able to perform this with custom fields on the resources, able to work with  % split roles the amount of capacity by role +ve and negative to give full capacity planning.  Managers able to see forecast resource capacity and down to an individual see how they were being utilised.

This was not real time, but an over night process that collated  the data into  set of Excel  pivots to give graphs on trend etc..

Worked a treat as it was even able to model  based on historic for different types and  classes of projects . Basically gave a detailed portfolio management facility, so even worked when projects had no detailed plans.  This was based on either forecast and actual.  Also  showed issues with the profile of projects e.g. optimistic testing profile, showed resource bottle knecks and  where high valued staff doing low valued tasks. Even identifying quality issues where  high % of rework on user stories  (no unit tests normally ) .